# OSX Xcode: Pre-filling bitmap with a specified RGB color?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there a method for filling a bitmap (context) with a specified RGB color?

Here is the procedure that I have implemented:

1. allocate memory for bitmap (malloc)
2. memset allocated memory with zeros (to get a black background)
3. Create CGContextRef:

   CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(memData, width, height,8,bytesPerRow,colorSpace,bmpInfo)
4. Insert image:

   CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(x,y,imgWidth, imgHeight), anotherImg)
5. Finalize image:

   CGImageRef createdImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)

As you can see from the above, the background will always be black. I want to be able to select an RGB color for the background. How is that done?

This is for an OSX app in XCode.

My functions are implemented in C as I'm not too comfortable with the Objective C syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fill colour (`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`) and then fill the whole context (`CGContextFillRect`).

Also, you might want to consider passing `NULL` as the `data` parameter to `CGBitmapContextCreate` so that you don't need to worry about the memory management for it.

Comment: Thank you!!! I thought I had to create valid data. If I pass in NULL, when is memory allocated and where ?

Comment: It should be allocated at the time - from the docs `you can pass NULL if you want Quartz to allocate memory for the bitmap. This frees you from managing your own memory, which reduces memory leak issues`